# Any free form input methods for any calendars in Emacs?

Tags: calendar

Is there anything like the `Quick Add` Google Calendar feature from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53483), for Emacs-based or other free calendars?

Basically, I would like a small program to parse unstructured English, like this:

```
14 december 11:20 at restaurant hermitage
```

and make it directly into an event in my calendar. LLM-based solutions are acceptable, but it should be a pretty small LLM for this task.

Comment: Have you searched ELPA? Use `M-x list-packages`.

Comment: I've searched ELPA and MELPA. There seems to be nothing about this, I am not even sure it would be a package, it should be incorporated into one of the calendar packages. I'm not even sure how to search correctly for it, since it's a thing that I've had trouble searching even generally. The only thing I found is that link.

Comment: Then you appear to have answered your question. Every new features needs to be written by someone; perhaps this is your time to shine.